# How can i add n nested for loops dynamically using recursion on this:

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, recursion, combinatorics

I would like to add N nested for loops dynamically, using recursion if possible, following this pattern on this code:

```
 Total = 4
 counter = 0
 for i in range(1, Total + 1):
     for j in range(i + 1, Total + 1):
         for k in range(j + 1, Total + 1):
             print(i, j ,k)
             counter += 1
 print(f"Number of combinations: {counter}")
```

The output will be all the combinations of 3 numbers in a total of 4 numbers(1, 2, 3, 4) in a sorted order, with the total of results:

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
2 3 4
Number of combinations: 4
```

Here´s my motivation, i want to dynamically increase the length of combinations.
 I would love something like `Total choose N elements`(which N is equal to the number of nested for loops in that pattern), and the only way that i found to do this is by hard coding N nested for loops with the previously pattern.

I have tried to implement this by myself with some similarly asked questions on `stackoverflow`, but i didn't succeed on make the for loops using recursion, with the wished pattern, and `itertools combinations` do not work if i want something like `a combination of 15 elements(set of length 15) from 25 in total`, like below:

```
#Adapted from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutation-and-combination-in-python/
# A Python program to print all
# combinations of given length
from itertools import combinations
Total = 25
n = 15
counter = 0
# Get all combinations of [1,2,3..25]
# and length n
comb = combinations([i for i in range(1, Total + 1)], n)

# Print the obtained combinations
for i in list(comb):
    print(i)
    counter += 1
print(f"Number of combinations: {counter}")
```

Expect output:

```
               1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
               1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 16
               1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 17
                              ...
               10 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
               11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
               Number of combinations:  3.268.760
```

Actual output is: `Killed`, but if hard code like below, it works pretty fine and gives the desired output:

```
def main():
    counter = 0
    for a in range (1, 26,1):
        for b in range (a + 1, 26,1):
            for c in range (b + 1, 26,1):
                for d in range (c + 1, 26,1):
                    for e in range (d + 1, 26,1):
                        for f in range (e + 1, 26,1):
                            for g in range (f + 1, 26,1):
                                for h in range (g + 1, 26,1):
                                    for i in range (h + 1, 26,1):
                                        for j in range (i + 1, 26,1):
                                            for k in range (j + 1, 26,1):
                                                for l in range (k + 1, 26,1):
                                                    for m in range (l + 1, 26,1):
                                                        for n in range (m + 1, 26,1):
                                                            for o in range (n + 1, 26,1):
                                                                print(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m , n, o)
                                                                counter += 1
    print(f"Number of combinations: {counter}")
main()
```

However, i cannot grow and shrink as needed the combination set. Would be nice to get it by growing and shrinking the number of nested for loops dynamically.
*Thanks people for the feedback

Comment: `"itertools combinations" fails`: How does it fail?

Comment: There's two reasons in it: if I do like 25 choose 15 the program do not work - it prints killed on the scream - and the length is not 15 only, it goes like 1 until 15. If I do like I showed it works, but looks badly coded and  not dinamic.

Comment: You should edit your question to post the failed program, your sample input, and your expected output to get a proper answer. I struggle to understand statements like `if I do like 25 choose 15 the program do not work`.

Comment: Alright, thank you, i will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itertools.combinations` method works fine for me. You might be running into memory issues if you are running it on a virtual machine/docker container with a tiny amount of memory. Python integers take 24 bytes, so you will need at least 74.8MB (24 * 3268760) of memory, plus the list overhead (around 25MB) to store the list.

Note that `list(comb)` will try to compute all combinations in advance and will consume memory. The tutorial you have been reading is wrong. You should directly use the iterator, i.e.

```
...
for i in comb:
    print(i)
    counter += 1
print(f"Number of combinations: {counter}")
```

If you are only after the number of items, you can use this trick to make it shorter:

```
counter = sum(1 for item in comb)
print(f"Number of combinations: {counter}")
```

Comment: Dude, that worked pretty well, thank you! Exactly, i´m running my code on a virtual machine.